# error when calling custom hook from onSubmit

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to React and I am trying to create a hook and call it from the onSubmit event but it gives me an error.

My code for the onSubmit function is the following:

```
    const onSubmit = ( event ) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setFormSubmited( true );
        if( !isFormValid ) return;
        
        const { send, setMessageuseMail } = useMail(); 
    }
```

The hook I created is called useMail and it is this

```
import { useState } from "react"

export const useMail = () => {
    const [send, setSend] = useState(false);
    const [messageMail, setMessageMail] = useState();

    setSend( true );
    setMessageMail(' Pruebas ');

    return {
        send,
        messageMail
    }
}
```

and the error it gives me is this:

> ERROR
> [eslint]
> src\components\ContactUs.jsx
> Line 43:45:  React Hook "useMail" is called in function "onSubmit" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

[Image Error](https://i.imgur.com/hUjrxOc.png)

I already tried to remove the word "use" from the file and I couldn't make it work, could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the call to `useMail` outside of the `onSubmit` function.

```js
const { send, messageMail } = useMail();
const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

React hooks need to be called at the top-level so they are called each time the component renders and in the same order.

Check out the documentation for the rules for hooks: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

The error message is saying React hooks must be called from either a component or another hook. If `onSubmit` is one of these, it needs to be updated to comply with the naming convention (capital for component, `use` for hooks). But in this case `onSubmit` isn't so we need to move where we're calling the hook.

Answer (score -1):

Change your component name to `UseMail`.

**React components must start with uppercase letter** as error clearly shows.

Comment: Hooks are not components.  Hook names start with `use______` (lower-case).

Comment: That's right, reading mistake.